# Is the plural form of the word "Sushi" really "Sushis"?

Tags: word-choice

I guess people know where I am from.

Why this question came to mind is [**this story**](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/sushi-salad-recall-products-pulled-210538752.html) made a top breaking news debut at Yahoo America (when I saw it).

Then a question came to my mind, what is the plural form of Sushi? They are eaten by a piece by a piece, so there should be the plural form. And I checked the Merriam (Unabridged(mine paid))

It says,

> plural -s

Apparently, when you read the article, the writer is using the word "Sushi" to mean the plural and I have never heard of any English speaker Sushis for plural use for over 30 years.

Am I correct that virtually English native speakers are not distinguishing between Sushi and Sushis like the plural form of [**fish (which is fish.)**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169472/fish-vs-fishes-for-plural-use)(which I previously asked before). Thank you for filling my interest in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on specific contexts.

Sushi can be countable or uncountable.
If you want more specific information, you can visit [this site](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/sushi.html)

Comment: It is better to extract information from outside sources, because those pages may expire.