# "fish" vs "fishes" Which one is correct here?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I know fish and fishes are both correct depending on the situation. But, what would you say in the following situation?

How many fish/fishes can you see in the lake? -> 5 fish/fishes

Comment: fishes is common in the Bible and literature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fish vs Fishes for plural use](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169472/fish-vs-fishes-for-plural-use)

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, there is variation in use.

Saying "fish" sounds rather more formal, and so would be the standard use, but a question like this would often be asked to a child or in an informal context, so "fishes" is equally correct.

Comment: I disagree heartily. We would not commonly say "How many fishes do you see in the lake?". fishes is either literary or archaic or some really odd local thing.

Comment: @Lambie Also commonly used in formal, technical contexts to talk about multiple *kinds* of fish: https://link.springer.com/journal/10641

Comment: I tend to disagree in this context.  "fishes" sounds childish, but no more.